# how to get image id in prestashop webservice

Tags: php, web-services, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I want to map image with combination of product.
below code can successfully added image but it is not giving me image id in return result.

**Code :**

```
$img_path = DIR_PATH_CONFIG.'/'.$this->filename.'_images/'. $imagename;
        //image will be associated with product id 4
        $url = PS_SHOP_PATH. '/api/images/products/'.$id_product;
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PUT, true); To edit a picture
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, PS_WS_AUTH_KEY.':');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('image'=>"@".$img_path.";type=image/jpeg"));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        if($result === false)
        {
        $var = false;
        echo "<br><br>Error : ".curl_error($result)."<br>"; }
        else 
        {
        echo '<br><br> Image added'; 
        //$xml = simplexml_load_string($result);
        //$imageId = $xml->image->id;
        unlink($img_path);
        $var = true;
        }
```

Can any one having idea please let me know..?

Answer (score 1):

Add an image to a product that has NO image (no entry is found in /api/images/products/{ID}). The key is creating a new CurlFile rather than just sending the binary of the image back to the PS WS. You can use the following function:

```html
/**
* Function that creates a new Product Feature Value and returns its newly created id
* @param product_id = the id of the product for which the image should be uploaded
* @param image_name = the String containing the name of the downloaded image (which will be found in /img)
* @return the ID of the newly inserted image
*/
function addNewImage( $product_id, $image_name  ) {
    $url = PS_SHOP_PATH . '/api/images/products/' . $product_id;
    $image_path = 'img/'. $image_name;
    $key = PS_WS_AUTH_KEY;

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:multipart/form-data','Expect:'));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $key.':');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('image' => new CurlFile($image_path)));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $result;
}
```